# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when trying to connect to wordpress database from outside script (same server)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pdo

I'm trying to input some values into the database for my website.

I'm using Wordpress as my CMS and so far I've been using $wpdb in functions.php successfully for the main website but what I'm working on now is part of the website but outside of the wordpress environment. This is because the wordpress part of the website is private but this is a small public-facing section.

For example, imagine the website was www.wordpresswebsite.com, the public part of the website is at www.wordpresswebsite.com/landing/ to serve as the publicly-facing "landing" part of the website.

This is not a plugin, the folder for this part of the website is outside of the wordpress installation so it can be outside of the private part of the website.

I thought I'd just be able to use PDO as I do on my non-wordpress websites as long as I had the correct database host, name, username and password from wp-config.php but I'm getting a '500 Internal Server Error' response when trying to run the php page and there's nothing in the error_log. I'm using include() to include the wp-config.php file at the start of my PHP file.

Here is just the simple example of my code that gives an error:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';', DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Is there something about the wordpress database setup that means I need to be doing something different? I was expecting to run into a few hiccups because I've never attempted this with a wordpress database before but I thought I'd at least get a PDO error not a generic '500 Internal Error' error.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

poncho

Answer (score 0):

You need to change PDO object second argument DB_HOST to DB_USER

### Exmple:

this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';', DB_HOST, DB_PASSWORD);
```

to:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Here the reference link [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

```
<?php

require_once('../wp-config.php');

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to insert a record
    // $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(column1,column2,column3) VALUES('value1','value2','value3')";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    // $db->exec($sql);


    echo "Record insert successfully";

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$db = null;

?>
```

Comment: Ah sorry yeah that's just a typo in the post, it is DB_USER in my code. Sorry for the confusion. It still doesn't work though.